# Статический фабричный метод или конструктор?

Tags: java

Когда следует использовать статический фабричный метод, а когда, лучше конструктор ? Для чего вообще нужен статический фабричный метод?

Comment: Конструктор всегда создает новый объект, а метод может уже отдавать существующий объект с определенными условиями. Например паттерн синглтон создает объект, когда его нет и отдает экземпляр, когда он уже существует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это хорошо описано в книге  Bloch Joshua "Effective java" во второй главе. Когда-то я делал пометки, вот они:

Преимущества статического метода:

- методы могут иметь понятные имена (легче обозначить какой именно объект нам нужен)
- мы можем не создавать экземпляр каждый раз при вызове метода (паттерн синглтон или, например, это делает возможным создание пула объектов, когда при одинаковых параметрах мы возвращаем один и тот же неизменяемый (immutable) экземпляр.
- мы можем вернуть объект любого наследника этого класса
- мы можем возвращать разных наследников на разные вызовы метода

Недостатки:

- мы не можем наследовать классы без конструкторов
- иногда сторонним разработчикам сложно понять, как инициализировать этот класс